# If DOB column is encrypted, how would I go about calculating the age of each person in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption, timestampdiff

I was given a database where the DOB column is encrypted with crypto. Assuming that the column has to stay encrypted, how would I go about getting/updating the age for each user?

Currently, I calculate the age using the code below :
(userBirthday is given in YYMMDD format and I calcualte the age before encrypting DOB)

```
function get_age(time) {
    var year = time.slice(0,4);
    var month = time.slice(4,6);
    var day = time.slice(6);
    //month is 0-indexed
    var years_elapsed = (new Date(new Date().getTime() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)) - new Date(year, month - 1, day))/(MILLISECONDS_IN_A_YEAR);
    return Math.floor(years_elapsed); 
}

let birthdayFull = req.body.userBirthday;
let birthYr = birthdayFull.slice(0,2);
let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear().toString().slice(2);

if(birthYr < currentYear) {
    birthdayFull = '20' + birthdayFull;
} else {
    birthdayFull = '19' + birthdayFull;
}
let age = get_age(birthdayFull);
```

Depending on the year, I either add '19' or '20' to get the date into a YYYYMMDD format. However, if I run the get_age function, I get an inaccurate answer. For example, if DOB is '19920215', the return value is 29, even though the user is still 28.

My question is 1. How would I calculate the user age accurately (getting the actual age, aka adding a year only if the actual birthday has passed) and 2. if I want to check for age updates everyday at midnight (to check if someone's age changed), how would I implement it if the DOB column is encrypted?

Comment: What threat are you protecting against? If I could a) observe an age column and b) on two successive days see it change, I pretty well know the DOB. So aren't you defeating the point of encrypting this value if your other requirements are met?

Comment: How do you encrypt the DOB?

Comment: It's gonna take a year, but I reckon I can hack this database.

Comment: I don't see any SQL in this question. What programming language is that?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I understand that by having a separate age column, the DOB would be eventually revealed if someone like Strawberry wanted to hack the db. I assume that the encryption is there so that the company is not solely responsible when there is a data breach (kind of as a formality).

Comment: @RiggsFolly I used the crypto package to implement asymmetric encryption. `const encryptedNum = crypto.publicEncrypt(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your two questions:

1. Subtract DoB from the current date, convert to years and round down
2. Holding data values that change based on a user's perspective (i.e. depending on what day they look at it) in a database is a really bad practice. You should calculate this dynamically when the user queries the data

**Update Following Comment**

1. Don't encrypt the DoB in the table. Remove user access from the table if you don't want people to be able to see the DoB
2. Create a View over the table that excludes or masks the DoB column. Add calculated columns to the view that display the age-related information that you want

Comment: There is a category where I could sort users by age group (19-24, 25-29, etc.). If a user were to turn 25 today, then the age column should be updated so that the user would fall under the 25-29 age group(this is why I want to try to check for updates everyday). Could you elaborate on  'calculate dynamically when the user queries the data'?  Given that the DOB column is encrypted, I thought it would be unnecessary to decrypt the DOB, loop through the data, and filter results.